# How to update nested object of array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redux

```
const testArr = [
    { id: 'aaa', 
      children: [ 
           { id: 'aaa-1', 
             children: [
                { id: 'aaa-1-1' }   
             ] 
           }, 
           { id: 'aaa-2'}
       ] 
    },
    { id: 'bbb' },
]
```

I am having nested array of objects to managa my `redux` store. I want to add new property to object. Let's add `children` to `id: aaa-2`, the object will be below:

```
const testArr = [
    { id: 'aaa', 
      children: [ 
           { id: 'aaa-1', 
             children: [
                { id: 'aaa-1-1' }   
             ] 
           }, 
           { id: 'aaa-2',
             children: [{ someNewKey: 'someNewValue' }]
           }

       ] 
    },
    { id: 'bbb' },
]
```

Is there a way to update nested level of object with specific key:value pair? I try to make function, but it's not working well

**I tried //** but it's not working properly when try to inner updates

```
const updateDeep = (arr, id, push) => {
    return arr.map(el => {
        if (el.id === id) {
             return Object.assign({}, el, { children: push }) 
            }
        else {
            if (el.children) {
                return updateDeep(el.children, id, push)
            } else {
                return el
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: In your example the new "children" element is a node - should it be a list?

Comment: Your code returns a new object, it doesn't modify the original object.

Comment: And if the object with the given ID already has any children, you replace them with the new `push` array, you don't add to the array. Is that what you want?

Comment: @SQLHacks Sorry, That was an mistake. I edited question.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, If the given ID already exists part I got it, but I don't have no idea of what you say first `it doesn't modify the original object`? I don't need to modify original object. It's okay just get copied one with new children added.

Comment: Do you want to add new children to the existing array, or replace the children completely with the value of `push`?

Comment: Your code works if you call it like this: `const newArr = updateDeep(testArr, "aaa-2", [{ someNewKey: 'someNewValue' }]);`. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar If children exist I want to push it, not replace completely.

Comment: @Barmar If I try nested one, the parent disappeared. that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

Resolve it myself

```
function updateDeep(array, id, newObj) {
    array.some((o, i) => {
        var temp;
        if (o.id === id) {
            o.children = [...(o.children ? o.children : []), newObj]
        }
        if (temp = updateDeep(o.children || [], id, newObj)) {
            o.children = [...(o.children ? o.children : []), newObj]
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `array.some()`, use `array.forEach()`.

Comment: I thought you didn't want to modify the object, you wanted to return a new object.